# Parse UDP packet into a bundle

Tags: tangle, iota-network, udp

I am exploring the https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.go for the purpose of running sort of "analysis" with my current remote node. I couldn't find any code that can parse/validate the transaction from a UDP packet. Is there any implementation available, or the Java IRI is the only vital source?

Comment: api libraries do not have control over fullnodes. Java IRI is indeed the only vital source to check what you are seeking.